# Nginx cloudflare 502 bad gateway

Tags: php, nginx, cloudflare

I'm using cloudflare. My site is working good but not loading any images, css files and js files.

[image: look that]

My server details;

> ubuntu 12.04
>
> nginx/1.1.19
>
> php5-fpm
>
> mysql

You can check live [here](http://www.sorbakalim.co)

Check with www and without www.

I think that problem is related to proxy (cloudflare)

> /etc/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;                                                                  
worker_processes 4;                                                             
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;                                                         
                                                                                
events {                                                                        
    worker_connections 768;                                                     
    # multi_accept on;                                                          
}                                                                               
                                                                                
http {                                                                          
                                                                                
    ##                                                                          
    # Basic Settings                                                            
    ##                                                                          
                                                                                
    sendfile on;                                                                
    tcp_nopush on;                                                              
    tcp_nodelay on;                                                             
    keepalive_timeout 65;                                                       
    types_hash_max_size 2048;                                                   
    # server_tokens off;                                                        
                                                                                
    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;                                         
    # server_name_in_redirect off;                                              
                                                                                
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;                                              
    default_type application/octet-stream;                                      
                                                                                
    ##                                                                          
    # Logging Settings                                                          
    ##                                                                          
                                                                                
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;                                       
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;                                         
                                                                                
    ##                                                                          
    # Gzip Settings                                                             
    ##                                                                          
                                                                                
    gzip on;                                                                    
    gzip_disable "msie6";                                                       
                                                                                
    # gzip_vary on;                                                             
    # gzip_proxied any;                                                         
    # gzip_comp_level 6;                                                        
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;                                                       
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;                                                    
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
                                                                                
    ##                                                                          
    # nginx-naxsi config                                                        
    ##                                                                          
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi                                 
    ##                                                                          
                                                                                
    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;                                       
                                                                                
    ##                                                                          
    # nginx-passenger config                                                    
    ##                                                                          
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger                             
    ##                                                                          
                                                                                
    #passenger_root /usr;                                                       
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;                                              
                                                                                
    ##                                                                          
    # Virtual Host Configs                                                      
    ##                                                                          
                                                                                
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;                                           
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;                                         
}
```

server conf

```
server {                                                                        
    #listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied          
    #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6                   
                                                                                
    root /usr/share/nginx/www/sorbakalim.co;                                    
    index index.html index.htm index.php;                                       
                                                                                
    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/                               
    server_name sorbakalim.co;                                                  
                                                                                
    location / {                                                                
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then                          
        # as directory, then fall back to index.html                            
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;                                        
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location                            
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules                                        
    }                                                                           
                                                                                
    location /doc/ {                                                            
        alias /usr/share/doc/;                                                  
        autoindex on;                                                           
        allow 127.0.0.1;                                                        
        deny all;                                                               
    }                                                                           
                                                                                
    # Only for nginx-naxsi : process denied requests                            
    #location /RequestDenied {                                                  
        # For example, return an error code                                     
        #return 418;                                                            
    #}                                                                          
                                                                                
    #error_page 404 /404.html;                                                  
                                                                                
    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html                  
    #                                                                           
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;                                      
    #location = /50x.html {                                                     
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/www;                                              
    #}                                                                          
                                                                                
    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000        
    #                                                                           
    location ~ \.php$ {                                                         
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;                               
        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini              
                                                                                
        # With php5-cgi alone:                                                  
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;                                            
    #   # With php5-fpm:                                                        
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;                               
        fastcgi_index index.php;                                                
        include fastcgi_params;                                                 
    }                                                                           
                                                                                
    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root                 
    # concurs with nginx's one                                                  
    #                                                                           
    #location ~ /\.ht {                                                         
    #   deny all;                                                               
    #}                                                                          
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the response isn't cached? All the images load fine on the link you posted. Usually the 502 error comes from an issue with communication to php

Comment: yes ofcourse, when im using cloudflare im getting thats error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 502 gateway generally indicates a temporary issue in a datacenter and you should [contact us](https://support.cloudflare.com/home) if you see this.

Things that are helpful in the report:
[Traceroute to the domain](https://support.cloudflare.com/entries/22050846-how-do-i-run-a-traceroute)

And the output from: http://yourdomain.com/cdn-cgi/trace (replace yourdomain.com with your actual domain).